# Count three (or more) many-to-many relations in template

Tags: django, django-templates, many-to-many

I have three models:

---

```
class Target(models.Model):
    fqdn = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ports = models.ManyToManyField('Port')

class Port(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    services = models.ManyToManyField('Service')

class Service(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    vuls = models.ManyToManyField('Vul')

class Vul(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

---

and a Template, where I want to count the vuls for a specific Target:

---

```
{% for t in targets %}
Target: {{ t.fqdn }}
Count Vuls: {{ t.ports.services.vuls.count }}
{% endfor %}
```

---

If I count the ports:

```
t.ports.count
```

there is no problem ...
But how counting "over" more than one many-to-many-relations?

Comment: yes it works t.ports.count.. but next level is won't work becuse of ambigutiy  to get all services count you need single instatace like p.services.count because target contains multiple ports and that multiple ports has multiple services, so it wont work use p.services.count

Comment: Are there any requirements that stop you from querying the counts in the view and then passing those to the template instead of doing the query in the template?

Comment: I think about get counts of vuls in the view. For now I pass a QuerySet of targets to the template ... maybe 100 targets. If I calculate the counts in my view, I have to pass a second structure (list, dict) to the template ... or not?

Answer (score 0):

I think to have a "solution" ...

```
class Target(models.Model):
    fqdn = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ports = models.ManyToManyField('Port')
    #counts vuls for every target
    def getSumVuls(self):
        sum = 0
        for p in ports.all():
            for s in p.services.all():
                sum = sum + s.vuls.count()
        return sum

class Port(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    services = models.ManyToManyField('Service')

class Service(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    vuls = models.ManyToManyField('Vul')

class Vul(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

in the template I call the getSumVuls()-method:

```
{% for t in targets %}
Target: {{ t.fqdn }}
Count Vuls: {{ t.getSumVuls }}
{% endfor %}
```

I'm not realy happy with this "solution" ... I think that performance is a problem!?!?